# XMLHttpRequest fails with Internet Explorer 10 for a visitor, despite working for my IE10 and Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I have created an XMLHttpRequest to fetch one RSS feed and one ATOM feed. It works fine for me with both Firefox and Internet Explorer 10. However, an IE10-using visitor to the site regularly gets error messages (though for a short while the error messages stopped before resuming a day or two later).

My regular error-catching script points me to the same line as the "send()" command and returns the error message "The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available". Additional information reported through a secondary error-catcher specifically for the XMLHttpRequest would be: readyState = 4, status = 0, statusText returns blank (no text, no 'null', just emptiness).

The website in question has a domain name with umlauts but I have made sure to use a relative address ('/some.url').

I have tried many different potential solutions found on the web but none seems to fix the problem. The visitor's browser was confirmed to be using the latest version of the javascript.

What could be causing this issue for the visitor?
How can I further determine the cause of the problem?
Is the problem avoidable?

```
if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
    try {
        var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch( e ) {
        var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
var feedtitle = '';
var feedno = 0;
var feedtype = '';
var feedmax = 1;
function feedcycler(n) {
    feedno = n+1;
    if (feedno == 2) {audrey('Forum','/forum/feed.php?mode=news','atom',10)};
    if (feedno == 1) {audrey('Press','/press/feed/','rss',1)};
}
function audrey(feedtitl,feed,feedt,feedm) {
    // 'feed' contains the actual url, the rest of the variables are used in 'feedme2'
    feedtitle = feedtitl;
    feedtype = feedt;
    feedmax = feedm;
    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch( e ) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if (xhr != null) {
        xhr.open("GET", feed, true);
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            var fs = '<div class="notes"><h3>'+feedtitle+'</h3>';
                fs += '<div>';
                    fs += 'Feed failure.'
                    fs += '<br/> State: ' + xhr.readyState;
                    fs += '<br/> Status: ' + xhr.status;
                    fs += '<br/> Text: ' + xhr.statusText;
                fs += '</div>';
            fs += '</div>';
            document.getElementById('news').innerHTML += fs;
        };
        xhr.onload = feedme1;
        xhr.send();
    }
    else {
        var fs = '<div class="notes"><h3>'+feedtitle+'</h3>';
        fs += '<div>Din webbläsare saknar AJAX-funktionalitet.</div>';
        fs += '</div>';
        document.getElementById('news').innerHTML += fs;
    }
}
function feedme1() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            feedme2(xhr)
        }
        else {
            console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
    }
}
function feedme2 (xhr) {
    // this function contains further processing, formatting and output of the data
}
```

Comment: status=0 means the the response wasn't processed.   What domain is the page running this script on, and what domain are you trying to fetch the URLs from?  Are they the same for your user as they are for you?  I ask because this sounds suspiciously like a cross-domain issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell from a screenshot that was sent to me, the visitor is using the same address format as I am (with the umlauts, rather than the alternate backwards-compatible format).

I am trying to fetch the URLs from the same domain using the relative addresses '/forum/feed.php?mode=news' and '/press/feed/'.

Comment: Ah, right - relative URLs = not a cross-domain issue, so ignore that.  I... don't have a good answer for you.  Can you look at your server logs to see if they're actually hitting your server?  The status=0 part implies their browser isn't receiving or processing a response.  That could happen for a variety of reasons.  You need to identify where in the control flow things are breaking down.

Comment: My website gets hundreds of unique visits every day, not sure how I would go about finding this one user among the statistics... What more can I do to "identify where in the control flow things are breaking down"?